# RavenDb LoadAsync Not Returning and Not Throwing Exceptions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, ravendb

I am trying to load a document out of RavenDb via a WebAPI call. When I open an async IDocumentSession and call LoadAsync, I get no exception or result, and the thread exits instantly with no error code.

I was able to bypass all the structure of my API and reproduce the error.

Here is the code that will not work:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetMyObject(long id)
    {
        try
        {
            var session = RavenDbStoreHolderSingleton.Store.OpenAsyncSession();
            var myObject= session.LoadAsync<MyObject>("MyObject/1").Result;

            return Ok(myObject);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return InternalServerError(e);
        }
    }
```

I simply hard coded the object's Id to 1 for testing, but calling the function for an object that doesn't exist (such as "MyObject/1") has the same result.

**However**, this code works:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMyObject(long id)
    {
        try
        {
            var session = RavenDbStoreHolderSingleton.Store.OpenAsyncSession();
            var myObject= await session.LoadAsync<MyObject>("MyObject/1");

            return Ok(myObject);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return InternalServerError(e);
        }
    }
```

Things I tried/fiddled with:

- Changing the exceptions that are caught in debugging
- Carefully monitoring Raven Studio to see if I could find any problems (I didn't, but I'm not sure I was looking in the right places)
- Running the API without the debugger attached to see if the error occurred or if something showed up in Raven Studio (no changes)

So I guess I have stumbled on a "fix", but **can someone explain why one of these would fail in such an odd way while the other one would work perfectly fine?**

In the real application, the API call did not have the async/await pair, *but* the code that *was* making the call was actually using async/await.

Here is the repository class that was failing which caused me to look into this issue:

```
    public async Task<MyObject> Load(string id) 
    { 
        return await _session.LoadAsync<MyObject>(id); 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part that is failing is as per design, for ASP.Net async call, you are blocking the Synchronization context, when you call the Result on a Task returned and same Synchronization context is required for call to return the data. Check out the following [link](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by **Stephen Cleary**, where the same mechanism is explained in detail.

Second part works since that is correct way of using it and it's not getting into the deadlock anymore. First part can only work if you are using the Console application, which doesn't have a synchronization context to block, even other UI like winforms will have a similar issue and need to use the use the Second part of the code

Comment: So threads that exit due to a deadlock still exit with a code of 0? And not some value that would indicate some sort of issue? This is starting to make a bit more sense - looks like I'll have to do a lot more digging on this topic.

Comment: No Deadlock means Threads don't exit, they remain perpetually in the blocked state, until and unless deadlock is resolved externally, like stopping process, killing one of the holding thread. Also deadlock doesn't mean an exception or error, so there will not be any error code as such